# Bring JSON data on a single select

Tags: mysql, json

I have a table called "menu", with a column called STRUCTURE. It was a "text-type" column, and contains a JSON with a menu structure referenced by IDs of another table called "category".

Ex: [{"id": 1}, {"id": 3}, {"id": 4}, {"id": 131}, {"id": 125}, {"id": 5}]

These IDs above are categories listed in the "category" table. However, to return in my website, it has been very heavy to perform, loop, within that loop make a "SELECT * FROM category WHERE id = 1, = 2", and so on ...

I read that there is a new type of column called JSON, which could reference information at query time. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Is it possible to make a query of this table "menu", and in it, return the infos of each ID of this JSON, in a single query?

Example that what i need (i dunno the syntax):

```
SELECT *, JSON_EXTRACT(menEstrutura, '$.*') as Data FROM sistema_menu WHERE menId = 1
```

Results:

```
ID  |  Title       |  Structure              |  Data (Virtual infos, this column doesnt exists)
1   |  Menu Header | [{"id": 1}, {"id": 3}]  |  [{"1":{"id":1,"title":"Cat 01","active":"true"},"2":{"id":2,"title":"Cat 02","active":"true"}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is **not** possible.
You'd have to `JOIN` informations into the `JSON`-Array.
So MYSQL would have to process/manipulate the JSON somehow.
(Maybe somebody else is able to post a Hack around this, now I'm curious.)

I don't think this is a good idea :-)

Maybe I can propose an alternative to you?

## Option 1: MySQL Left-Join

```
ID          | Sorting | CategoryID
-----------------------------------
menu_header | 1       | 7
menu_header | 2       | 6
menu_header | 3       | 8
```

In this example I'm using ID,SORTING as Composite Primary Key `PRIMARY KEY(ID, Sorting)`.

Then you have a normalized table and you could [Join](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/left-join.php) the informations you need from the `categories`-table.

```
SELECT `ID`, c.Title, c.Url, c. as menu FROM menus m
    LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.ID = m.CategoryID
    ORDER BY `Sorting`
```

Now you have all the information you need with one query :-)

## Option 2: Build the table async

You could also use the programming language of your choice to do the complex Query async.

Maybe:

- once a day
- when a someone updates a category
- when someone updates a menu
- manually

It's not that important that you use a complex query to determine the menu if you do it async and story it as an array, in redis or whatever ;-)

## More (maybe helpful infos) on building a menu

### `active` state

Do not store `active` in your database.
Check the state later, in your code.

(This will improve your Cache-Hit-Ratio)

### Multi Level navigation

If you need that (sorry, I'm not sure why you're using JSON, thinking of a `children` attribute or something):

Here is a nice article about [Patterns for Storing Tree Structures in the RDBMS](https://railsware.com/blog/2013/07/15/storing-tree-structures-in-the-rdbms/).

Comment: You're a nice guy, thanks for reply. I was trying to avoid the first approach because the system was already in production for many years and would generate a lot of work. But I see that maybe it really is the best idea. About the "active" column, is just a flag to know what row are ready to go, or is being mediated. Ill read the article for the tree pattern structure!

Comment: You can still use **Option 2**.
Use your current structure and build Option 1 from it (async).
Replace the Query-Part of your Application only.

You then have a so called "presentation" of your data.
The data is still stored in the originial way, you have just optimized the query-side :-)